# jqWdigets TreeTable facing following error in angular2 code : addButton.jqxButton

Tags: angular, typescript

HI am using JqWidgets treegrid, But facing following errors in angular2 code:

```
core.js:1598 ERROR TypeError: addButton.jqxButton is not a function
    at b.(:4200/anonymous function).AppComponent.renderToolbar [as rendertoolbar] (http://localhost:4200/main.js:161:23)
    at b.(:4200/anonymous function)._render (http://localhost:4200/main.js:2073:46696)
    at push../src/assets/jqwidgets/jqxdatatable.js.b.jqx.dataView.dataview.update (jqxdatatable.js:7)
    at q (jqxdatatable.js:7)
    at Object.l [as func] (jqxdatatable.js:7)
    at push../src/assets/jqwidgets/jqxdata.js.i.jqx.dataAdapter.callDownloadComplete (jqxdata.js:7)
    at Object.success (jqxdata.js:7)
    at bw (jqxcore.js:7)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jqxcore.js:7)
    at S (jqxdata.js:7)
```

Code :

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

import { jqxTreeGridComponent } from './jqtree/angular_jqxtreegrid';
import { jqxButtonComponent } from './jqtree/angular_jqxbuttons';

import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild('TreeGrid') treeGrid: jqxTreeGridComponent;

    employees: any[] = [
        { "EmployeeID": 1, "FirstName": "Nancy", "LastName": "Davolio", "ReportsTo": 2, "Country": "USA", "Title": "Sales Representative", "HireDate": "1992-05-01 00:00:00", "BirthDate": "1948-12-08 00:00:00", "City": "Seattle", "Address": "507 - 20th Ave. E.Apt. 2A" },
        { "EmployeeID": 2, "FirstName": "Andrew", "LastName": "Fuller", "ReportsTo": null, "Country": "USA", "Title": "Vice President, Sales", "HireDate": "1992-08-14 00:00:00", "BirthDate": "1952-02-19 00:00:00", "City": "Tacoma", "Address": "908 W. Capital Way" },
        { "EmployeeID": 3, "FirstName": "Janet", "LastName": "Leverling", "ReportsTo": 2, "Country": "USA", "Title": "Sales Representative", "HireDate": "1992-04-01 00:00:00", "BirthDate": "1963-08-30 00:00:00", "City": "Kirkland", "Address": "722 Moss Bay Blvd." },
        { "EmployeeID": 4, "FirstName": "Margaret", "LastName": "Peacock", "ReportsTo": 2, "Country": "USA", "Title": "Sales Representative", "HireDate": "1993-05-03 00:00:00", "BirthDate": "1937-09-19 00:00:00", "City": "Redmond", "Address": "4110 Old Redmond Rd." },
        { "EmployeeID": 5, "FirstName": "Steven", "LastName": "Buchanan", "ReportsTo": 2, "Country": "UK", "Title": "Sales Manager", "HireDate": "1993-10-17 00:00:00", "BirthDate": "1955-03-04 00:00:00", "City": "London", "Address": "14 Garrett Hill" },
        { "EmployeeID": 6, "FirstName": "Michael", "LastName": "Suyama", "ReportsTo": 5, "Country": "UK", "Title": "Sales Representative", "HireDate": "1993-10-17 00:00:00", "BirthDate": "1963-07-02 00:00:00", "City": "London", "Address": "Coventry House Miner Rd." },
        { "EmployeeID": 7, "FirstName": "Robert", "LastName": "King", "ReportsTo": 5, "Country": "UK", "Title": "Sales Representative", "HireDate": "1994-01-02 00:00:00", "BirthDate": "1960-05-29 00:00:00", "City": "London", "Address": "Edgeham Hollow Winchester Way" },
        { "EmployeeID": 8, "FirstName": "Laura", "LastName": "Callahan", "ReportsTo": 2, "Country": "USA", "Title": "Inside Sales Coordinator", "HireDate": "1994-03-05 00:00:00", "BirthDate": "1958-01-09 00:00:00", "City": "Seattle", "Address": "4726 - 11th Ave. N.E." },
        { "EmployeeID": 9, "FirstName": "Anne", "LastName": "Dodsworth", "ReportsTo": 5, "Country": "UK", "Title": "Sales Representative", "HireDate": "1994-11-15 00:00:00", "BirthDate": "1966-01-27 00:00:00", "City": "London", "Address": "7 Houndstooth Rd." }
    ];

    source: any =
    {
        dataType: "json",
        dataFields: [
            { name: 'EmployeeID', type: 'number' },
            { name: 'ReportsTo', type: 'number' },
            { name: 'FirstName', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'LastName', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'Country', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'City', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'Address', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'Title', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'HireDate', type: 'date' },
            { name: 'BirthDate', type: 'date' }
        ],
        hierarchy:
        {
            keyDataField: { name: 'EmployeeID' },
            parentDataField: { name: 'ReportsTo' }
        },
        id: 'EmployeeID',
        //url: '../assets/sampledata/locations.tsv',
        localData: this.employees,
        addRow: (rowID, rowData, position, parentID, commit) => {
            // synchronize with the server - send insert command
            // call commit with parameter true if the synchronization with the server is successful 
            // and with parameter false if the synchronization failed.
            // you can pass additional argument to the commit callback which represents the new ID if it is generated from a DB.
            this.newRowID = rowID;
            commit(true);
        },
        updateow: (rowID, rowData, commit) => {
            // synchronize with the server - send update command
            // call commit with parameter true if the synchronization with the server is successful 
            // and with parameter false if the synchronization failed.
            commit(true);
        },
        deleteRow: (rowID, commit) => {
            // synchronize with the server - send delete command
            // call commit with parameter true if the synchronization with the server is successful 
            // and with parameter false if the synchronization failed.
            commit(true);
        }
    };

    dataAdapter: any = new jqx.dataAdapter(this.source);

    newRowID = null;
    theme: string = '';
    buttonsObject: any = null;

    updateButtons(action: string, buttons: any): void {
        switch (action) {
            case 'Select':
                buttons.addButton.jqxButton({ disabled: false });
                buttons.deleteButton.jqxButton({ disabled: false });
                buttons.editButton.jqxButton({ disabled: false });
                buttons.cancelButton.jqxButton({ disabled: true });
                buttons.updateButton.jqxButton({ disabled: true });
                break;
            case 'Unselect':
                buttons.addButton.jqxButton({ disabled: true });
                buttons.deleteButton.jqxButton({ disabled: true });
                buttons.editButton.jqxButton({ disabled: true });
                buttons.cancelButton.jqxButton({ disabled: true });
                buttons.updateButton.jqxButton({ disabled: true });
                break;
            case 'Edit':
                buttons.addButton.jqxButton({ disabled: true });
                buttons.deleteButton.jqxButton({ disabled: true });
                buttons.editButton.jqxButton({ disabled: true });
                buttons.cancelButton.jqxButton({ disabled: false });
                buttons.updateButton.jqxButton({ disabled: false });
                break;
            case 'End Edit':
                buttons.addButton.jqxButton({ disabled: false });
                buttons.deleteButton.jqxButton({ disabled: false });
                buttons.editButton.jqxButton({ disabled: false });
                buttons.cancelButton.jqxButton({ disabled: true });
                buttons.updateButton.jqxButton({ disabled: true });
                break;
        }
    }

    renderToolbar = (toolBar) => {
        let toTheme = (className) => {
            if (this.theme == '') return className;
            return className + ' ' + className + '-' + this.theme;
        }
        // appends buttons to the status bar.
        let container: any = $('<div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>');
        let buttonTemplate: any = '<div style="float: left; padding: 3px; margin: 2px;"><div style="margin: 4px; width: 16px; height: 16px;"></div></div>';
        let addButton: any = $(buttonTemplate);
        let editButton: any = $(buttonTemplate);
        let deleteButton: any = $(buttonTemplate);
        let cancelButton: any = $(buttonTemplate);
        let updateButton: any = $(buttonTemplate);
        container.append(addButton);
        container.append(editButton);
        container.append(deleteButton);
        container.append(cancelButton);
        container.append(updateButton);
        toolBar.append(container);
        addButton.jqxToggleButton ({ cursor: 'pointer', enableDefault: false, disabled: true, height: 25, width: 25 });
        addButton.find('div:first').addClass(toTheme('jqx-icon-plus'));
        addButton.jqxTooltip({ position: 'bottom', content: 'Add' });
        editButton.jqxButton({ cursor: 'pointer', disabled: true, enableDefault: false, height: 25, width: 25 });
        editButton.find('div:first').addClass(toTheme('jqx-icon-edit'));
        editButton.jqxTooltip({ position: 'bottom', content: 'Edit' });
        deleteButton.jqxButton({ cursor: 'pointer', disabled: true, enableDefault: false, height: 25, width: 25 });
        deleteButton.find('div:first').addClass(toTheme('jqx-icon-delete'));
        deleteButton.jqxTooltip({ position: 'bottom', content: 'Delete' });
        updateButton.jqxButton({ cursor: 'pointer', disabled: true, enableDefault: false, height: 25, width: 25 });
        updateButton.find('div:first').addClass(toTheme('jqx-icon-save'));
        updateButton.jqxTooltip({ position: 'bottom', content: 'Save Changes' });
        cancelButton.jqxButton({ cursor: 'pointer', disabled: true, enableDefault: false, height: 25, width: 25 });
        cancelButton.find('div:first').addClass(toTheme('jqx-icon-cancel'));
        cancelButton.jqxTooltip({ position: 'bottom', content: 'Cancel' });

        this.buttonsObject = {
            addButton: addButton,
            editButton: editButton,
            deleteButton: deleteButton,
            cancelButton: cancelButton,
            updateButton: updateButton,
        };

        addButton.click((event) => {
            if (!addButton.jqxButton('disabled')) {
                this.treeGrid.expandRow(this.rowKey);
                // add new empty row.
                this.treeGrid.addRow(null, {}, 'first', this.rowKey);
                // select the first row and clear the selection.
                this.treeGrid.clearSelection();
                this.treeGrid.selectRow(this.newRowID);
                // edit the new row.
                this.treeGrid.beginRowEdit(this.newRowID);
                this.updateButtons('add', this.buttonsObject);
            }
        });

        cancelButton.click((event) => {
            if (!cancelButton.jqxButton('disabled')) {
                // cancel changes.
                this.treeGrid.endRowEdit(this.rowKey, true);
            }
        });

        updateButton.click((event) => {
            if (!updateButton.jqxButton('disabled')) {
                this.treeGrid.endRowEdit(this.rowKey, false);
            }
        });

        editButton.click(() => {
            if (!editButton.jqxButton('disabled')) {
                this.treeGrid.beginRowEdit(this.rowKey);
                this.updateButtons('edit', this.buttonsObject);
            }
        });

        deleteButton.click(() => {
            if (!deleteButton.jqxButton('disabled')) {
                let selection = this.treeGrid.getSelection();
                if (selection.length > 1) {
                    for (let i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
                        let key = this.treeGrid.getKey(selection[i]);
                        this.treeGrid.deleteRow(key);
                    }   
                }
                else {
                    this.treeGrid.deleteRow(this.rowKey);
                }
                this.updateButtons('delete', this.buttonsObject);
            }
        });
    };

    rowKey = null;

    rowSelect(event: any): void {
        let args = event.args;
        this.rowKey = args.key;
        this.updateButtons('Select', this.buttonsObject);
    };

    rowUnselect(event: any): void {
        this.updateButtons('Unselect', this.buttonsObject);
    };

    rowEndEdit(event: any): void {
        this.updateButtons('End Edit', this.buttonsObject);
    };

    rowBeginEdit(event: any): void {
        this.updateButtons('Edit', this.buttonsObject);
    };

    columns: any[] = [
        { text: 'FirstName', columnGroup: 'Name', dataField: 'FirstName', width: 200 },
        { text: 'LastName', columnGroup: 'Name', dataField: 'LastName', width: 200 },
        { text: 'Title', dataField: 'Title', width: 160 },
        { text: 'Birth Date', dataField: 'BirthDate', cellsFormat: 'd', width: 120 },
        { text: 'Hire Date', dataField: 'HireDate', cellsFormat: 'd', width: 120 },
        { text: 'Address', dataField: 'Address', width: 250 },
        { text: 'City', dataField: 'City', width: 120 },
        { text: 'Country', dataField: 'Country' }
    ];

    columnGroups: any[] =
    [
        { text: 'Name', name: 'Name' }
    ];

    ready(): void {
        this.treeGrid.expandRow(2);
    };
}
```

Comment: Please add the code which you are using

Comment: @niladri : added code. some formatting issues.